# CSS issue when resizing browser

Tags: css, browser

I am facing a problem in poitioning the window:

When I resize the window my CSS falied; I mean look of the page is changed:

Here is the code:

Webpage:

```
         <!-- Begin Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Begin Header -->
  <div id="header">
  <h1>
     Header
  </h1>
  </div>
  <!-- End Header -->

  <!-- Begin Navigation -->
  <div id="navigation"> 
  <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="current">One</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">asd</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">fdasdasd</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasdasd</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">fsadfsd</a></li>
               </ul>
          </li>
            <li><a href="/faq.php">Two</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sdfsdfasdf</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sdfsdf</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sdfsdaf</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">werqwer</a></li>
                </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/faq.php">Three</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">safdfwe</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sdafdf</a></li>
                </ul>
          </li>


            <li><a href="/contact/contact.php">My Account</a>

            </li>
            <li>
               <input type="text" style="width:200px;" id="search" />
               <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- End Navigation -->
  <!-- Begin Left Column -->
  <div id="leftcolumn">


   </div>
  <!-- End Left Column -->
  <!-- Begin Content Column -->

  <div id="content"> 

   </div>
  <!-- End Content Column -->
  <!-- Begin Right Column -->
  <div id="rightcolumn"> 

  </div>
  <!-- End Right Column -->
  <!-- Begin Footer -->
  <div id="footer"> 


   </div>

  <!-- End Footer -->
 </div>
<!-- End Wrapper -->
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 menu{
    border:none;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font: 67.5% "Tahoma", "Verdana", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
.menu ul{
    background:#333333;
    height:35px;
    list-style:none;
     display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
    .menu li{
        float:left;
        padding:0px;
        }
    .menu li a{
        background:#333333 url("images/seperator.gif") bottom right no-repeat;
        color:#cccccc;
        display:block;
        font-weight:normal;
        line-height:35px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px 25px;
        text-align:center;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
        .menu li a:hover, .menu ul li:hover a{
            background: #2580a2 url("images/hover.gif") bottom center no-repeat;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            text-decoration:none;
            }
    .menu li ul{
        background:#333333;
        display:none;
        height:auto;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        border:0px;
        position:absolute;
        width:225px;
        z-index:200;
        /*top:1em;
        /*left:0;*/
        }
    .menu li:hover ul{
        display:block;

        }
    .menu li li {
        background:url('images/sub_sep.gif') bottom left no-repeat;
        display:block;
        float:none;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        width:225px;
        }
    .menu li:hover li a{
        background:none;

        }
    .menu li ul a{
        display:block;
        height:35px;
        font-size:12px;
        font-style:normal;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px 10px 0px 15px;
        text-align:left;
        }
        .menu li ul a:hover, .menu li ul li:hover a{
            background:#2580a2 url('images/hover_sub.gif') center left no-repeat;
            border:0px;
            color:#ffffff;
            text-decoration:none;
            }
    .menu p{
        clear:left;
        }
```

Full screen mode:

[image]

Resize browser:

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a horizontal scrollbar when the window is resized, add a [`min-width`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-width) on the outermost `div`:

```
#wrapper {
    min-width: 960px
}
```

Answer (score 3):

add width to your menu example

```
menu { width: 890px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please view the demo
http://jsfiddle.net/abdulwakeel/FVewx/

i have fixed it with menu ul

```
        #menu ul{ min-width:960px}
```